# Copy folder structure from one Outlook account to another

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I've seen a lot of info on copying folder structure from one .pst file to another empty one (i.e. if you run out of space), but that's not what I'm looking for.

My company was recently purchased, and I now have two separate email accounts to maintain - one with myname@oldcompany.com and one with myname@newcompany.com.

I have a pretty intricate structure of almost 100 folders, and would rather not have to recreate it manually in the newcompany.com account if I don't have to.

Is there any easy way to copy a folder structure (minus contents) from one account to another? We do use office365, if that makes a difference (I can use either the web interface or the desktop client on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible in two steps:

1. Archive the oldcompany emails into a PST file, specifying a far date
   in the past so only folders are archived
2. Import the PST into newcompany.

I don't have your environment so cannot test.
You probably already know how to execute these two steps, but here are
some references that might help:

- [How to copy folder structure to new pst data file in Outlook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2385-outlook-copy-folder-structure-new-pst.html)
  Shows the archiving process.
- [Use network upload to import your organization PST files to Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/use-network-upload-to-import-pst-files?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fuse-network-upload-to-import-your-organization-s-pst-files-to-office-365-103f940c-0468-4e1a-b527-cc8ad13a5ea6)
- [Import PST File into Exchange Online](https://web.archive.org/web/20180419140939/http://www.thatlazyadmin.com/import-pst-file-exchange-online/)

This is just an idea for which I don't have the environment for testing.